# How to forward a remote UNIX_AF socket to a local port with ssh

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, unix

I'm trying to forward a remote UNIX_AF socket to a local port through ssh, but it fails with the message:

`Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen path /path/to/sock`

I tried to run `ssh user@host -R /path/to/sock:localhost:44434` with the socket both being bound (with python's socket module) and unbound and it didn't work.

The reason I want to use a Unix socket is the lack of any open ports that would work with ssh.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “lack of open ports”? There’s billions(!) of ports in _127.0.0.0/8_. Surely they aren’t all in use? // Are you sure the server does not forbid remote port/socket forwarding?

Answer (score 0):

`ssh -R /path/to/sock:localhost:44434` you used tries to make `sshd` on the server side *listen* on `/path/to/sock`.

If `/path/to/sock` already exists on the server side then it must be removed before your `ssh -R` can work. [An automatic solution exists](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/429903/108618), it requires `StreamLocalBindUnlink` to be `yes` on the server (in `sshd_config`). If you cannot configure the server this way then you should `ssh … 'rm /path/to/sock'` first, before `ssh -R`. (`StreamLocalBindUnlink` exists as an option for `ssh` but I think it applies to sockets created on the client side; [some say it's a bug](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2601).)

With `StreamLocalBindUnlink` being `yes` on the server or if `/path/to/sock` doesn't exists on the server side, your `ssh -R` should work. `sshd` serving your SSH connection will create `/path/to/sock` on the server side and it will listen on it. Your remote Python program will be able to connect to it.

It's not clear if you want your Python program to listen or to connect. If your remote Python program must necessarily listen on a socket then `sshd` serving your SSH connection must connect to the socket. In such case locally you need `ssh -L`; but then `ssh` will listen locally. If you want the local end of the tunnel to initiate connections (as opposed to listening), then use `ssh -R` and make sure the remote Python program (or whatever) connects to the socket file, not tries to listen on it.

Technically one can establish an indirect connection between two listening parties or between two non-listening parties, but it's not easy (if possible at all) with sole `ssh`. I think `socat` with two non-listening or two listening ends can be used, respectively, as a relay (next to `ssh -R` or `ssh -L` which is also a relay). In any case, for any direct connection in a chain, a listening process must be started before a connecting process tries to connect.